# Net Core - convert html table to list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, html-table

I have an html table. new rows are added to this table with javascript. In order to add the rows from this table to the database, I want to get the rows from this table in the form of a list on the controller side. How can I do that?

Comment: you can give the table tags different ids, fetch their values by getElementById and send them via ajax to a controller. In controller side you define an action that before its declaration, you write [HttpPost] and define a route.

Comment: Can you share a similar example link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a simple demo here about using javascript to add rows and send data from table to controller, Hope it can help you.

**View**

```
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Add New User</h2>
    
        Name:<input type="text" id="Name"/>
        Age:<input type="text" id="Age"/>
        Country:<input type="text" id="Country"/>
        <p></p>
        <input type="button" value="Add" id="insert" onclick="add()"/>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered zero-configuration dataTable" role="grid" id="TestTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Jack</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>USA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nacy</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>China</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lily</td>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>UK</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>

<input type="button" value="Update" id="Update" onclick="Update()"/>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
    function add(){
        
         var name = $("#Name").val();
         var age = $("#Age").val();
         var country = $("#Country").val();
         var tr = "<tr><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+age+"</td><td>"+country+"</td>></tr>"
         $("#TestTable").append(tr);
         
     }
     </script>
    <script>
    function Update(){
         var result = [];
         var tr = $("#TestTable tr");              
                 for (var i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) 
                 {
                        var tds = $(tr[i]).find("td");
                        if (tds.length > 0) {
                            result.push({
                                "Name" : tds[0].innerHTML,
                                "Age" : tds[1].innerHTML,
                                "Country" : tds[2].innerHTML
                            })
                        }
                        
                        
                 }
                    var jsonData = { 
                        "personLst" : result
                    }
                 $.ajax({
                    dataType: 'json',            
                    type: "Post", 
                    data: jsonData,
                    url: "/Home/Privacy"
                    
                 })
                 
                
    }
    </script>

}
```

**Model**

```
public class UserTest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Privacy(List<UserTest> personLst)
    {
        //.......
        return View();
    }
```

**Demo**

[image]

Then I click Update button, the data will be send to controller.

[image]